# Unable to SET or RESET GPIO PA12 on STM32F030

Tags: c, stm32, uart, gpio, stm32f0

**I am having some trouble trying to SET or RESET one of my GPIO pins on the STM32F030.**

I'm using the STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver and I initialize GPIO PA12 like this:

```
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_MEDIUM;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

I also set my UART using the folowing code:

```
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600; 
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_ENABLE;
  huart1.gState = HAL_UART_STATE_RESET;

  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;

  HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);
```

I know PA12 *can* be used as UART1_RTS pin but I'm not setting the hardware-flow-control to use RTS or CTS.

**The problem I'm facing**:
After code initialization I **can** receive messages over the UART1 connection.
To reply I need to set a pin of an external IC which I'm trying to set using PA12.
But when I call:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

nothing happens..

Also calling the GPIO_PIN_RESET won't do anything..

**What am I missing here??**

I've checked (and measured) the PCB, PA12 is only connected to 0V with a 10k pull-down resistor, the external IC isn't pulling the PA12 output low.

**Many thanks in advance!**

**edit:**

As requested in the comments, my UART pin configuration:

```
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_USART1;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

I'm using DMA to set the Rx:

```
    /* DMA controller clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* DMA interrupt init */
    /* DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    hdma_usart1_rx.Instance = DMA1_Channel3;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_usart1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;

    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart1_rx);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn);
```

**2nd EDIT!:**

I just found that re-initializing the GPIO PA12 **after** the UART initialization works!
I can now toggle PA12 without any problems..

But this is not the way it should be!
I'm looking into the STM32 HAL-lib but can't find the piece of code that sets PA12...

Comment: Your configuration seems to set pullup non pulldown

Comment: This is correct, I have an external pull-down (when the STM32F0 is starting up, I want PA12 to be pulled down).
I added the internal pull-up because I thought the PIN was having a hard time delivering enought current. (I have experienced this with a low-current pin before).
But adding the internall-pull-up doesn't do the trick :(

Comment: The Pull-Up/Dow is not necessary since the output function is "much stronger" than the weak internal pull resistors.

Comment: Could you post your USART pin initialization ( and maybe search for any occurrence of ´GPIO_PIN_12` so see if the config is changed somewhere else).

Comment: Could not find any other call to GPIO_PIN_12 except for my own pin-initialization

Comment: Have you tried a clean project to just toggle the pin like:

`RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;
GPIOA->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE3_12);
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE3_12;
GPIOA->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_OD12`

Comment: @Damiano I tried your method and it worked, the pin toggles. I also tried the STM32 HAL GPIO driver and this works too.. I guess it has to do with the DMA functionality.. I noticed that I'm not setting the UART1_Rx pin but it still works by simply calling the DMA functionality..

Comment: I just found that I can keep toggling the pun UNTILL I call: HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);

Comment: I could use some externation from Linus to describe you my consideration of the ST HAL library.

Comment: I feel you, there are so manny little errors in this library..

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the GPIOA Clock?

`__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();`

Edit:

Please have a look at your `void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)` function to see which and how the pins for the usart are configured.

Comment: Good comment, yes I did.
All other pins on the GPIOA port can be SET and RESET.. except for PA12.
I also used another PCB but this gives the same result

Comment: I wonder if PA12 isn't in an alternative mode by default?
I know AF_UART1 will set it as RTS pin

Comment: In my HAL_UART_MspInit() I have: UNUSED(huart); and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the *clean* solution I really wanted..

But initializing this single pin **after** the UART initialization seems to do the trick..

PA12 is being set in the UART initialization but I was not able to find the piece of code doing so anywhere

Comment: You should have an HAL_UART_MspInit implementation thats hardware dependend (outside HAL driver).... there should be the code that initializes the pins. (probably generated by your ide)

Comment: HAL_UART_MspInit is not overridden and just has "UNUSED(huart);"

Comment: Are you sure? It cannot work this way. Maybe that one you found is just a weak function and there some other implementation around, maybe masked by some macros. Just try to debug it till it get called.

Comment: Well, if you've initilized it yourself, it isn't needed of course

Comment: Debugged it, only thing it is calling is the UNUSED() function. I guess the MCU itself sets the pin at UART initialisation??

Comment: It seems really strange. Could you just dump the gpio configuration after HAL_UART_Init()? You could also put a watchpoint on the registry that been written by it.